# how to use variable for @include name inide @each loop SCSS

Tags: sass, include, each

I want to replace this SCSS code with @each usage.

```
body{
  @include us(){
    @include define-breakpoint("us")
  }
  @include xs(){
    @include define-breakpoint("xs")
  }
  @include sm(){
    @include define-breakpoint("xs")
  }
  @include md(){
    @include define-breakpoint("md")
  }
  @include lg(){
    @include define-breakpoint("lg")
  }
  @include xl(){
    @include define-breakpoint("xl")
  }
}
```

When I use @each function compiler throws out an error - invalid css with @include **#{$bp}**(){...}

```
$list: us xs sm md lg xl;
  @each $bp in $list{
    body{
    @include #{$bp}(){
      @include define-breakpoint("#{$bp}")
    }
    }
  }
```

Does everybody know how to handle this error?
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this code is that interpolation can't be used to *convert* a *variable* to an *identifier*. The Sass compiler won't allow it. At the point where you interpolate `$bp`, the compiler expects an identifier. It will treat anything at that point as an identifier and not something that should be interpolated.

From your code it appears you've defined several `mixins` with `@content` passed within the block like so

```
@mixin us() { @content; }
@mixin sm() ( @contnet; }
```

which is why they are called like so

```
@include us(){
  @include define-breakpoint("us");
}
```

You could refactor your code to make use of only one `mixin` since the only thing that's actually changing is the code in the block.

```
$list: us xs sm md lg xl;

@mixin screen-size() { @content; }

body {
  @each $size in $list {
    @include screen-size() {
      @include define-breakpoint($size);
    }
  }
}
```

Another option would be to define the mixin to take a parameter instead and have the code within that block include the `define-breakpoint` mixin passing the parameter as an argument.

```
$list: us xs sm md lg xl;

@mixin screen-size($size) { 
  @include define-breakpoint($size); 
}

body {
  @each $size in $list {
    @include screen-size($size);
  }
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

To achieve the added functionality specified in your code you can make the following adjustments to the previous answer

```
//list now takes media query also
$list: 'us' '(max-width: 519px)',
       'xs' '(min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 767px)',
       'sm' '(max-width: 768px)',
       'md' '(min-width: 769px)',
       'lg' '(min-width: 519px) and (max-width: 960px)',
       'xl' '(min-width: 961px)';

//mixin takes media query as argument
@mixin screen-size($query) {
  @media #{$query} {
    @content;
  }
}

body {
  @each $map in $list {
    @include screen-size( nth($map, 2) ) {
      @include define-breakpoint( nth($map,1) );
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My mixins for screen contain media queries:
    '@mixin us() {
       '@media (max-width: 519px) {
           '@content;
        }
    }
    '@mixin xs() {
       '@media (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 767px) {
          @content;
       }
   }
so if I replace these mixins with '@mixin screen-size(){'@content}, how can I take into account media queries?

Comment: I've taken that into consideration and updated my previous answer. It should work to your expectation now.

Comment: in second mixin we don't need to use $nth($map,1), just nth($map,1)

Comment: and I need to have a string in my mixin define-breakpoint
@mixin define-breakpoint($name){
  &:after{
    content: "#{$name}";
    display: none;
  }
}

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out, it should have been `nth` and not `$nth`. If you want the values to be strings, they just need to be altered in the `$list` variable. Surround them in quotes instead eg `'us'`, `'xs'`... and so on. I've edited the code to show what the `$list` variable should look like. I hope those changes should be sufficient